# LinearLayout in separate file doesn't work

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, layout

I've got next code:

```
public class YazCalcActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)this.findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setup();

        TabHost.TabSpec calculateSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Calculate");
        calculateSpec.setIndicator("Calculate");
        calculateSpec.setContent(R.id.calculateLayout);

        TabHost.TabSpec solveSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Solve");
        solveSpec.setIndicator("Solve");
        solveSpec.setContent(R.id.solveLayout);

        tabHost.addTab(calculateSpec);
        tabHost.addTab(solveSpec);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
}
```

And the main.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                <LinearLayout
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:id="@+id/calculateLayout" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Button" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:id="@+id/solveLayout" >

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="CheckBox" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that if I paste code of calculateLayout and solveLayout in separate XML-files and do calculateSpec.setContent(R.layouts.calculatelayout) instead of calculateSpec.setContent(R.id.calculateLayout) - the application crashes on start.

Why???

**upd**
Error log:

> 02-10 19:55:02.988: W/dalvikvm(31196): threadid=3: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x4001b168) 02-10 19:55:02.988:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(31196): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to
>   uncaught exception 02-10 19:55:03.018: E/AndroidRuntime(31196):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.ia01.yazcalc/com.ia01.yazcalc.YazCalcActivity}:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create tab content because could
>   not find view with id 2131034112 02-10 19:55:03.018:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(31196):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
>   02-10 19:55:03.018: E/AndroidRuntime(31196):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
>   02-10 19:55:03.018: E/AndroidRuntime(31196):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119) 02-10
>   19:55:03.018: E/AndroidRuntime(31196):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
>   02-10 19:55:03.018: E/AndroidRuntime(31196):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 02-10
>   19:55:03.018: E/AndroidRuntime(31196):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 02-10 19:55:03.018:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(31196):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363) 02-10
>   19:55:03.018: E/AndroidRuntime(31196):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 02-10
>   19:55:03.018: E/AndroidRuntime(31196):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 02-10 19:55:03.018:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(31196):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
>   02-10 19:55:03.018: E/AndroidRuntime(31196):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 02-10
>   19:55:03.018: E/AndroidRuntime(31196):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 02-10 19:55:03.018:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(31196): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could
>   not create tab content because could not find view with id 2131034112
>   02-10 19:55:03.018: E/AndroidRuntime(31196):  at
>   android.widget.TabHost$ViewIdContentStrategy.(TabHost.java:587)
>   02-10 19:55:03.018: E/AndroidRuntime(31196):  at
>   android.widget.TabHost$ViewIdContentStrategy.(TabHost.java:578)
>   02-10 19:55:03.018: E/AndroidRuntime(31196):  at
>   android.widget.TabHost$TabSpec.setContent(TabHost.java:435) 02-10
>   19:55:03.018: E/AndroidRuntime(31196):    at
>   com.ia01.yazcalc.YazCalcActivity.onCreate(YazCalcActivity.java:18)
>   02-10 19:55:03.018: E/AndroidRuntime(31196):  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   02-10 19:55:03.018: E/AndroidRuntime(31196):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
>   02-10 19:55:03.018: E/AndroidRuntime(31196):  ... 11 more

**upd2**

I've cleaned the project, but nothing has changed. BUT. I found info about this issue. I can't set "layout" as a content directly, because I need to create the View form this layout first. So I've changed the code in next way:

```
public class YazCalcActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)this.findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setup();

        TabHost.TabSpec calculateSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Calculate");
        calculateSpec.setIndicator("Calculate");
        View calculateView = this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.calculatelayout, null);
        calculateSpec.setContent(calculateView.getId());

        TabHost.TabSpec solveSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Solve");
        solveSpec.setIndicator("Solve");
        View solveView = this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.solvelayout, null);
        calculateSpec.setContent(solveView.getId());

        tabHost.addTab(calculateSpec);
        tabHost.addTab(solveSpec);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
}
```

But, I'm still getting the same error. Wow...

**upd3** Solved.

Well, I've fixed this shit. I just had to use the "include":

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        <include layout="@layout/calculate_layout" 
            android:id="@+id/calculateTab" />
        <include layout="@layout/solve_layout" 
            android:id="@+id/solveTab" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Could you post the crash log?

Comment: Done, the log is in the post.

Comment: You need to use `LayoutInflater` to inflate the layouts (i.e., create `View` instances) before using those views to set the tab content.

Comment: Yep, I got it. But see the upd2, please.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the log

```
Could not create tab content because could not find view with id 2131034112
```

Do the following:

1- Save all of your files.
2- Select Project > Clean

Try to re-run the program and let me know if it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've fixed this. I just had to use the "include":

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <include layout="@layout/calculate_layout" 
        android:id="@+id/calculateTab" />
    <include layout="@layout/solve_layout" 
        android:id="@+id/solveTab" />
</FrameLayout>
```